# How to improve the efficiency of this code to sort numbers using simulated annealing concept?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, simulated-annealing

I am trying to understand the concept of simulated annealing ,therefore I tried to implement it to sort numbers .I am not sure whether this is conceptually correct implementation of the simulated annealing. Can anyone guide me on how to implement it properly in this case?
How can I improve the score function in this case?  Also ,I have not been able to implement the concept of Temperature here.Please bear with me ,as I am a beginner in programming.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
void print(vector<int> x)
{
  for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
  {
     cout<<x[i]<<"->";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
int score(vector<int> x)
{
   int s=0;
   for(int i=0;i<x.size()-1;i++)
   {
      for(int j=i+1;j<x.size();j++)
      {
        if(x[j]<x[i])
        s++;
      }
   }
   return s; 
}
map<vector<int> ,int>h;
int main()
{ 
  vector<int> x;
  srand(time(0));
  int N=20;// vector size 
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    x.push_back(rand()%10000);
  }
  int it=0;
  while(it<5000)
  {
      if(score(x)==0)  // score =0 stop;  
      {
         print(x);
         cout<<"done in iterations"<<it<<endl;
         break;
      }
      int a=rand()%N;
      int b=rand()%N;
      swap(x[a],x[b]);
      vector<int>y=x;
      swap(x[a],x[b]);
      if(h.find(y)!=h.end())   continue;
      if(score(x)>score(y))
      {
           x=y;
      }
      //print(x);
      it++;
  }
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: This is not a free [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. What effort did you make and where did you get stuck? Where is the bottle-neck of your code? What is your expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: @Shahbaz:Thanks for closing the question,it really helped and encouraged me as a beginner to keep on using SO.

Comment: @Shahbaz:perhaps it wasn't clear to you,but I did not ask how my code looks even once.I was asking whether I was implementing the concept  correctly. I am very shocked by your rashness in closing the question.

Comment: Couple minutes after you wrote your question, you already had 2 closing votes. It's not just me who thinks this is not a good question. I, at least, cared enough to explain to you why your question is going to be closed (as you can see, I was vote 3 out of 5, so there were two more after me too). First of all, we are not free debuggers. We are here to help you and we like to see you make an effort before asking. I know its tempting to just ask and get an answer instead of research, but that's abusing us.

Comment: Second, if you think about it, how is this question, in its current form, ever going to help anybody else? Do you think anyone would google "how to improve user1907531's number-sort algorithm using simulated annealing"? From your other comments, it seems like you have a deeper problem with understanding how temperature is implemented. You may want to ask a better question regarding how temperature in simulated annealing is implemented (after doing your research), which is more likely to attract and help other people too.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with simulated annealing, it's simply a hill-climbing random sort. The crucial property of simulated annealing is that it will occasionally accept a worse answer in its search, which your code never does.

Comment: it also should make big changes in the beginning and as the system cools it should make smaller and smaller changes (but I guess that's what the meant by saying the didn't implement temperature)

Comment: Yes I was able to understand the concept of temperature,but can you please guide me with how to implement Temperature for this case.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:Yes I meant exactly what you wrote.Thanks